# Github SSH is connected but fails when cloning a repository into Digital ocean droplet

Tags: github, digital-ocean

I'm setting up a laravel website with a Digital Ocean droplet.
This process is so difficult and frustrating, I'm losing logic sense...
I'm connected with an ssh key that is connected with github, because I tried this code to test my connection:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

with this as response:

```
> Hi (My name)! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
> provide shell access.
```

So it is connected.
However, when I want to clone my repository into my online droplet. I get the error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I have no idea how to fix this..
My ssh key inside my digital ocean settings is the same as in my github ssh settings.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution myself!

So what was the problem?

I was using the ssh key from my localhost as an access key for cloning private github repositories. That is why I couldn't clone into an online service because that online service has it's own specific ssh key. So inside my server, I generated an ssh-key and registered that one on github. When I tried cloning me repo inside my droplet
everything worked as it should do.